# Why do I get a compiler warning for converting a string literal to a char*, is it bad?

Tags: c++, c-strings, string-literals

So the compiler tells me this is a deprecated conversion from a string-literal to char*:

```
 char* myString = "i like declaring strings like this";
```

Should I be worried about this? Is this the wrong way to do this?

I need to pass `myString` to a function that accepts a `char*` , who should I properly initialize the `char*` without this conversion?

Comment: This shouldnt compile, since it isnt valid C++ anymore. Its was only supported in the beginning of C++ to make porting C-code to C++ easier (since C has no `const`).

Comment: @smerlin "C has no `const`"? Yes it does, and I think it has since C89.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Oops, you are correct. C has const, but allows implicit conversion to non-const. C-Compilers don't diagnose code like `char * x = "FOO"; x[0] = 'B';`.

Comment: @smerlin C compilers do give you a warning when you implicitly convert `const` to non-`const`. The reason that snippet doesn't warn you is that string literals aren't `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't even compile. If you need to pass it to function that you are sure won't change the string you need to use const cast, its one of its correct uses:

```
functionName(const_cast<char *>("something"));
```

Or if you don't want the const cast, you can copy the string to the stack:

```
char str[] = "something";
functionName(str);
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, You should be worried about it!

You should be declaring it as:

```
const char* myString = "i like declaring strings like this";
```

`mystring` is an pointer to the string literal `"i like declaring strings like this"`, and the string literal resides in an memory space(Implementation Defined) which should not be modified by your program.
Modifying a string literal results in **Undefined behavior**.

Hence, C++03 Standard deprecated declaring string literals without the keyword `const`, This ensures that the string literal cannot be modified through the pointer.

---

Answer to your Question Edit, is already posted by @Benjamin in comments, simply quoting his answer:

> Use an array:
>   char myString[] = "i like declaring strings like this";
>   That copies the literal into the array, and the copy can be modified

Comment: In C++, it is illegal. In C++03 it is deprecated.

Comment: Just so our terms are clear, mystring is not a string literal, it is a pointer. `"i like declaring strings like this"` is a string literal. +1 anyway because you got the important part.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thanks for pointing that subtle important detail out.

Comment: Ok thanks much! that makes sense. but I need to pass a char* to a function, How can i create the char* without this conversion?

Comment: @weezybizzle: That is a No No! If your function takes a `char *` then ideally it does not guarantee that it won't modify the string pointed by the pointer,Doing so in this case would cause UB.

Comment: @weezybizzle: Use an array: -- `char myString[] = "i like declaring strings like this";` -- That copies the literal into the array, and the copy can be modified.

Comment: @weezybizzle: The simplest and straightforward solution is what Benjamin Lindley suggested.

Comment: but what if my function needs to modify the string? I should use a `const char*` parameter and then copy it into a char*?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That is working for me, thanks much for the simple solution.